# Can I disable GNOME legacy tray in 17.04?

Tags: 17.04, gnome-shell, system-tray

The legacy tray (see the screenshot below) will be removed in GNOME 3.26. I want to wean myself off it before the change arrives in Ubuntu (17.10 or 18.04).

[image]

Can I disable the legacy tray in Ubuntu GNOME 17.04?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Several [GNOME shell extensions](https://askubuntu.com/q/75530/480481) can do that.

- [Hide Legacy Tray](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/967/hide-legacy-tray/) will just hide it.
- [TopIcons Plus](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1031/topicons/) will move
  the items from the tray to the top bar. It's cool and has many
  customize options like icons color saturation, padding and size.