# GNOME shell Ubuntu 16.04 - How to disable notification area

Tags: 16.04, gnome-shell, system-tray

I have just Installed GNOME Shell on Ubuntu 16.04.

There a area in layout I don't know what is it name exactly.
This area in below picture (Area 1):

[image]

I think some Icon in area 1 should be in area 2 (taskbar) and I already install a test Ubuntu with Gnome shell in another PC, it exactly in taskbar.

My question is how to disable area 1 and how to move icon in area 1 to area 2 (taskbar)?

Comment: *Area 1* is called the "legacy tray", use TopIcons Plus as suggested here: [Can I disable GNOME legacy tray in 17.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/948673/can-i-disable-gnome-legacy-tray-in-17-04)

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked.